# Match each primitive with relevant directives in GraphicsComplexBox

Tags: graphics, pattern-matching

I am struggling to write the correct pattern to match all `ArrowBox` objects with the relevant graphic directives in following snippet

```
{
    Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]],
    {
        Arrowheads[0.],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.606341, 0.514848}, 2}], 0.0127299]
    },
    ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.10576, 0.352183}, 3}], 0.0127299], 
    ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.499413, 0.70158}, 3}], 0.0127299],
    {
        Arrowheads[0.],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.500581, 1.03046}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    }, 
    ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.890575, 0.349397}, 1}], 0.0127299], 
    ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{3, {0.391162, 0.515612}, 1}], 0.0127299]
}
```

To generate the same code, use this snippet which extracts it from a `GraphicsComplexBox`:

```
g = Block[{Identity}, 
  Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
    EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]];
Cases[ToBoxes[g], _GraphicsComplexBox, Infinity][[1, 2, 1]]
```

I try to improve the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169265/13042 so it works with other graphs as well. The following part of the solution in the referenced answer does not work as intended for the above given graph:

```
Cases[ToBoxes[g], {dir___, ar : Longest[__ArrowBox], ___} :> 
(## & @@ Thread[{dir, {ar}}]), Infinity]
```

It returns

```
{
    {
        Arrowheads[0.], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.606341, 0.514848}, 2}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[0.], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.500581, 1.03046}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Arrowheads[0.], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.10576, 0.352183}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.606341, 0.514848}, 2}], 0.0127299], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.499413, 0.70158}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    }
}
```

There are several issues

- the last two `ArrowBox` objects are missing
- contains a duplicate `ArrowBox`, and
- graphic directives are not properly handled.

The output should look like

```
{
    {
        Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Arrowheads[0.], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.606341, 0.514848}, 2}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.10576, 0.352183}, 3}], 0.0127299]},
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.499413, 0.70158}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Arrowheads[0.], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.500581, 1.03046}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.890575, 0.349397}, 1}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{3, {0.391162, 0.515612}, 1}], 0.0127299]
    }
}
```

General scheme is

```
{
    directivesLevel1,
    RepeatedPattern[ primitive | {directivesLevel2, primitive}]
}
```

which should return with the replacement rule

```
{
    {directivesLevel1, primitive} OR
    {directiveslevel1, directivesLevel2, primitive},
    ...
}
```

**Other graphs for more extensive testing**

```
g2 = Block[{Identity}, 
  Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 7,
    6 <-> 7, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 6 -> 4, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 1, 5 -> 7}, 
    EdgeWeight ->  Identity /@ Join[Table[{0, 0}, 10], {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1},
        {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]]

g3 = Block[{Identity}, 
  Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6,
    1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 4, 5 -> 3, 6 -> 3, 6 -> 2}, 
    EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ Join[Table[{0, 0}, 9], Table[{0, 1}, 3], Table[{1, 0}, 3]]]]
```

To see all errors, run

```
ClearAll[displayWeightedMultiGraph]
displayWeightedMultiGraph = Module[{i = 1, j, g = #, bcurves,
  labels = PropertyValue[#, EdgeWeight], 
  gccoords = Cases[ToBoxes[#], GraphicsComplexBox[x_, y_, z___] :> x, Infinity][[1]]}, 
  bcurves = Cases[ToBoxes[g], {dir___, ar : Longest[__ArrowBox], ___} :> 
    (## & @@ Thread[{dir, {ar}}]), Infinity] /. 
  {ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[x_, y___], z___] :> 
     Arrow[BezierCurve[x /. k_Integer :> gccoords[[k]], y], z], 
   ArrowBox[x : {__}, y_] :> Arrow[gccoords[[x]], y]}; 
   SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> ({j = i++; Text[labels[[j]], 
     BezierFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 7][0.5]], bcurves[[j]]} &)]] &;

displayWeightedMultiGraph/@{g, g2, g3}
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you are trying to "unravel" the directive dependencies and get a list in which a directive is assigned explicitly to each `ArrowBox`?

Comment: Yes, I think you got me right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FilledCurve inside GraphicsComplex doesn't interpret the integers as points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/filledcurve-inside-graphicscomplex-doesnt-interpret-the-integers-as-points)

Comment: @CarlWoll: Can you explain why do you think this is a duplicate and a (possible) bug in Mathematica and if and how the given workaround could help me? I am not too experienced with Mathematica and it is not obvious how to apply the given workaround. Therefore I think my question could get its own answer with a link to the other one.

Comment: @CarlWoll: The mentioned workaround moves manually the problematic primitive outside of the GraphicsComplex. I am interested in doing it automatically for different graphs. Editing manually the low-level box representation is not an answer to this question.

Comment: For a graph `g`, it is much simpler to use `Show` to convert it to a `Graphics` object. Then, the function `Normal` is documented to convert a `Graphics` object with a `GraphicsComplex` to one without any `GraphicsComplex` objects. The fact that `Normal` fails is a bug and has already been covered in questions [(105184)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105184/45431) and [(104818)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104818/45431).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I think it's much more straightforward to use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) to create the equivalent [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object. Then, you can use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) to convert the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) into normal primitives. However, there is an issue with [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) and [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) objects that are nested inside of other primitives, partly discussed in [(104818)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104818/45431). For example:

```
Normal @ GraphicsComplex[
    {{1,1}, {1.25,1.75}, {2,2}},
    Arrow[BezierCurve[{1, 2, 3}], .1]
]
```

> {Arrow[BezierCurve[{1, 2, 3}], 0.1]}

The integer indices of the [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) have not been replaced with the coordinates from the first argument of the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex). On the other hand, when the primitives are not nested, [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) works:

```
Normal @ GraphicsComplex[{{1,1}, {1.25,1.75}, {2,2}}, BezierCurve[{1, 2, 3}]]
Normal @ GraphicsComplex[{{1,1}, {1.25,1.75}, {2,2}}, Arrow[{1, 2, 3}, .1]]
```

> {BezierCurve[{{1, 1}, {1.25, 1.75}, {2, 2}}]}
>
> {Arrow[{{1, 1}, {1.25, 1.75}, {2, 2}}, 0.1]}

Here is a patch the fixes the nested [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) issue:

```
Unprotect[Normal];
Normal[g_] /; !TrueQ@$BZFix := Block[{$BZFix=True},
    Normal[g /. gc_GraphicsComplex :> fixGC[gc]]
]

fixGC[GraphicsComplex[pts_, prim_, rest___]] := GraphicsComplex[
    pts,
    prim /. BezierCurve[p_, r___] :> BezierCurve[p /. i_Integer :> pts[[i]], r],
    rest
]
```

Check:

```
Normal @ GraphicsComplex[{{1,1}, {1.25,1.75}, {2,2}}, Arrow[BezierCurve[{1, 2, 3}], .1]]
```

> {Arrow[BezierCurve[{{1, 1}, {1.25, 1.75}, {2, 2}}], 0.1]}

For your first example graph:

```
g = Block[{Identity}, 
    Graph[
        {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
        EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}
    ]
];
```

We get:

```
Normal @ Show @ g //InputForm
```

> Graphics[{{Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], 
>      {Arrowheads[0.], Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0.49692221124371655, 0.}, {0.6063408473035717, 0.5148479095999602}, 
>          {0.9999936484762257, 0.8642449331499502}}], 0.012729919145102353]}, 
>      Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0.49692221124371655, 0.}, {0.1057602447225488, 0.3521832484933547}, {0., 0.8677950164043108}}], 
>       0.012729919145102353], Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0.9999936484762257, 0.8642449331499502}, 
>         {0.49941304589520347, 0.7015802720433176}, {0., 0.8677950164043108}}], 0.012729919145102353], 
>      {Arrowheads[0.], Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0.9999936484762257, 0.8642449331499502}, 
>          {0.5005806025810231, 1.0304596775108001}, {0., 0.8677950164043108}}], 0.012729919145102353]}, 
>      Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0.9999936484762257, 0.8642449331499502}, {0.8905750124163706, 0.3493970235499975}, 
>         {0.49692221124371655, 0.}}], 0.012729919145102353], 
>      Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0., 0.8677950164043108}, {0.3911619665211691, 0.5156117679108979}, {0.49692221124371655, 0.}}], 
>       0.012729919145102353]}, {Directive[Hue[0.6, 0.2, 0.8], EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.7]]]], 
>      Disk[{0.49692221124371655, 0.}, 0.012729919145102353], Disk[{0.9999936484762257, 0.8642449331499502}, 
>       0.012729919145102353], Disk[{0., 0.8677950164043108}, 0.012729919145102353]}}, 
>    {FormatType -> TraditionalForm, FrameTicks -> None}]

You'll notice that all of the [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) objects have actual coordinates, available to be extracted by your `displayWeightedMultiGraph` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a possible solution

```
primitiveQ[p_] := Head[p] === ArrowBox;
directiveQ[d_] := Head[d] === Arrowheads || Head[d] === Directive;
list = Cases[ToBoxes[g], _GraphicsComplexBox, Infinity][[1, 2, 1]];
dirlevel1 = Cases[list, _?directiveQ];
Cases[list, ar_?primitiveQ|{dir___,ar_?primitiveQ} :> Flatten[{dirlevel1, dir, ar}]]
```

This returns

```
{
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Arrowheads[0.],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.606341, 0.514848}, 2}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{1, {0.10576, 0.352183}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.499413, 0.70158}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Arrowheads[0.],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.500581, 1.03046}, 3}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{2, {0.890575, 0.349397}, 1}], 0.0127299]
    },
    {
        Arrowheads[Medium], Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]],
        ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[{3, {0.391162, 0.515612}, 1}], 0.0127299]
    }
}
```

Remaining improvements

- remove duplicate directives keeping the last (here `Arrowheads`)
- better predicates `primitiveQ` and `directiveQ`

I am not too experienced: maybe this code contains unnecessary copies of lists.